# Wiimote on linux mint – recognised perfectly as event in /dev/input, but not as js

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kernel, joystick, wiimote

I spent the day trying to get my wiimote to work on my linux mint machine. The results are mixed. Using xwiimote or rather xwiishow I could determine that every sensor and button inside the device works, as well as all attachments that I own. I get the same results when using evtest on /dev/input. However, all the tools of the joystick (jscal, jstest, jstest-gtk) have trouble with recognising input from the directional pad(s) and the nunchuck attachment.

I'm basically out of ideas. I thought the problem might lie with bluez, but as connecting the device works flawless since I got xwiimote running, I'm thinking it's a kernel problem to do with how linux manages joysticks / gamepads.

Is there any way I could just copy inputs from the proper event to a js in /dev/input? Or does anyone else have a solution in mind?

I already did try qjoypad, but this doesn't recognise the d-pad either, and creates some other problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

Current linux kernel automatically maps d-pad input from wiimote/classic controller to keyboard arrow keys. Question solved in regard for being able to use the whole thing via qjoypad now, re-mapping the whole thing would probably require compiling the kernel myself.